# how to calculate sum of amounts for the accounts in two tables depends on the first characters part

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables tblaccounts + tblamounts

in **tblaccounts** I have AccID, AccCode, AccType(Main or Sub) fields

in **tblamounts** I have AccID, TheAmount fields

I need to calculate the total amounts for each account but the role is as you can see in the next data:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| AccCode | Amount | AccType |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 1       | 2400   | Main    |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 11      | 1600   | Main    |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 111     | 100    | Sub     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 112     | 1000   | Sub     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 113     | 500    | Sub     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 12      | 800    | Main    |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 121     | 500    | Sub     |
+---------+--------+---------+
| 122     | 300    | Sub     |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

the amounts for (Main)12 = Sub121(500)+Sub122(300) = 800

the amounts for (Main)11 = Sub111(100)+Sub112(1000)+Sub113(500) = 1600

the amounts for (Main)1 = Main11(1600)+Main12(800) = 2400

I tried to sum each account depending on the first number so if I want to get the sum of AccCode(1) I must find the accounts that start with 1 and sum all their amounts, but how to check the other accounts that contain more than 1 character like 12, I want to give amount 121 + 122

Updates:
I used the next code:

```
SELECT AccCode, 
(
SELECT SUM(TheAmount) xResult FROM tblamounts
INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblamounts.AccID 
WHERE AccCode LIKE xacc.AccCode%
) FROM tblaccounts xacc
```

Comment: (Main)1 = Main11(800)+Main12(1600) should be (Main)1 = Main11(1600)+Main12(800) ?

Comment: What's the hierarchy here - is the first character the grandparent the second character the parent and the third character the child? can you have more than 3 levels?

Comment: @P.Salmon The father is 12 so 121 and 122 are the children, the father is 1 so 11 and 12 are the children so If I need the amounts of 12 so I should find the accounts that start with 12 and calculate them.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your schema

Comment: @Strawberry how to get the accounts that start with 12 as an example, I used left() fun but there is a missed thing I don't know what it's

Comment: According to your previous comment Kamsaw's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select a.*,
       (select sum(am.amounts)
        from amounts am
        where am.accId like concat(a.accId, '%')
       )
from accounts a;
```

That is, sum the values from all accounts that start with the same characters of a given account.

Comment: The father is 12 so 121 and 122 are the children, the father is 1 so 11 and 12 are the children so If I need the amounts of 12 so I should find the accounts that start with 12 and calculate them

Comment: I need during getting account records for each account loop on other accounts that start with the account that we want to get its amount

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. You could hack a correct answer using CHARLENGTH in conjunction with the above, but that is going to be ugly

Comment: @Hamada . .  And `121 like 12%` matches, so the children are included.  This would seem to do what you want.  You can set up a db<>fiddle if you want to show why you think it wouldn't work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see the Updates that I did in the main post, I think I just need to change Where part

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that solution is good but I need your help to correct it please

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
```
        SELECT AccCode, 
        (
        SELECT SUM(TheAmount) xResult FROM tblamounts
        INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblamounts.AccID 
        WHERE AccCode LIKE xacc.AccCode%
        ) FROM tblaccounts xacc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to sum up to, but not including the Account itself (only all the accounts below it)

```
SELECT a.AccCode AS AccountCode, 
(SELECT SUM(tblamounts.TheAmount) FROM tblamounts, tblaccounts g 
WHERE tblamounts.AccID = g.AccID AND (g.AccCode LIKE CONCAT(a.AccCode,'%') 
AND NOT (g.AccCode = a.AccCode AND LOWER(a.AccType) = 'main'))) AS AccountSum ,
 a.AccType AS AccountType 
 FROM tblaccounts a;
```

So in your result AccountCode 12 will be the sum of 121 and 122.
The assumption is that AccountType 'Main' will not have its own amount, and will only be a sum of the 'Sub' account types starting with similar code.

Answer (score -1):

Easy solution
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
select sum(Amount) from tab where AccCode LIKE "12_"

select sum(Amount) from tab where AccCode LIKE "11_"

select sum(Amount) from tab where AccCode LIKE "1_"
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT m1.AccCode, sum(m2.Amount) from tab m1
inner join tab m2 on m2.AccCode LIKE m1.AccCode || "_"
where m1.accType = "Main"
group by m1.AccCode
```

Comment: SELECT AccCode, 
(
SELECT SUM(TheAmount) xResult FROM tblamounts
INNER JOIN tblaccounts ON tblaccounts.AccID = tblamounts.AccID 
WHERE AccCode LIKE xacc.AccCode%
) FROM tblaccounts xacc

it gives me an error when I use xacc.AccCode